# How to listen to sensors in an Android application

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to build and android application (my first android app and I just started building it) and it must work like this

1. It should run in background.
2. It constantly listens to sensors (say accelerometer) and do some tasks when it receives some signal even when the phone is locked or screen blacked out.

EDIT How do I make sure my services are not killed in background and if they do get killed, they get initiated as soon as possible. I read that services do get killed by system to retrieve memory, but how are they restarted? For starting service when phone is rebooted, there is a configuration, will that same configuration work for services killed by system?

Comment: please add more detail of the problem to your question. you will get more accurate aproaches and directions

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Service` that implements the desired sensor listeners.

This `Service` should return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand` so it restarts when OS destroyed it for some reason.

Then, in your application, you are able to start and stop the Service easily from some `Activity` using the following methods: `startService` and `stopService`.

If those "some tasks" must run in parallel you can make use of Java threads using or not the `Executors` Java framework.

If a task needs to *Toast* some message to the user you need to use an `Handler` and a custom `Runnable` because the service does not run in the UI thread and `Toast.makeText()` does.

**References:**

- [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
- [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)
- [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)
- [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: you're welcome. you should not ask for tutorials here because your question may be closed. Edit it and if possible add more detail about what are you trying to achieve.